# Camera preview using GLSurfaceView

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-camera, glsurfaceview

I am trying to implement android camera preview using GLSurfaceView. Following is the code on [Github](https://github.com/muneikh/OpenGLCamera)

```
@Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
        Timber.d("mVideoInputSource.isReady(): " + mVideoInputSource.isReady());

        if (this.mVideoInputSource.isReady()) {
            Timber.d("mVideoInputSource.nextFrame() is called ");
            this.mVideoInputSource.nextFrame();
        }
    }

    public void nextFrame() {
        if (this.mSurfaceTexture != null) {
            this.mSurfaceTexture.updateTexImage();
            this.mSurfaceTexture.getTransformMatrix(this.mTransform);
            mFullScreen.drawFrame(mTextureId, this.mTransform);
            checkOrientationChanged();
        }
    }
```

After running the program, I am only getting the black screen. Could someone highlight, if what I am missing over here?

Comment: The code you posted could certainly work given the right set of circumstances. You'll need to figure out how it's supposed to work, and what it's actually doing. For example, if mSurfaceTexture is null, nothing will be drawn, but nobody here can tell you if your field is null. You need to look at logcat output, check values with log statements or a debugger, etc.

Comment: Thanks Fadden, mSurfaceTexture was null. You can put the comment as an answer and I would be happy to accept it.